# Populating 'half' of the database in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have been working on populating data within a table in ASP.Net Visual Studio 2012. I was able to write code (in c#) so when a person goes into my website and registers, their data is inputted straight into my database table I've created (found within the server explorer).

Now this table is called "members" for those now part of my database.

However the data that is inputted into the "members" table does not fill the entire data on the row.

I have the user details but not the last two data that requires other details such as 'recent book user has read' and 'their favorite novel genre'. They are both null.

[image]

I want to know, how can I possibly (on a different web page) populate the rest of the row in the database table?

I wanted to create this in another web form (not the registration page) so for the member to fill out, and there (once submitted) I would like the last two data to be filled (within the same row).

Please let me know if seeing my code with make it easier to assist.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that is a MySQL database?

Comment: Have you heard about UPDATE command? Although you need id for that one

Comment: @TusharGupta I have but in what way do I use the UPDATE command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question directly first, you need to use UPDATE

For example:

```
UPDATE tablename 
SET recentbook = @recentbook, 
    favgenre = @favgenre 
WHERE username = @username
```

This question is a really a simple database concept, commonly known as `CRUD` (Create, Read, Update, Delete)

- Create = [INSERT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html)
- Read = [SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html)
- Update = [UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html)
- Delete = [DELETE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/delete.html)

Please reefer to the manual links above to find more information and continue your learning.

Comment: Sorry but username is not unique(not mentioned), you have to give a unique id to update

Comment: @TusharGupta while you're correct, you are also very petty - if username is unique or not is totally irrelevant to the actual question, you could simply add `WHERE username = @username AND email = @emailAddress` etc or something else to make the where condition unique, Its very likely that as the OP is storing details there is something there to identify the row - the links to the MySQL manual will explain how to use `UPDATE` correctly. The OP didn't post a full DDL so you know that is not unique as much as I know it is! - Thanks anyway for the down vote.

Comment: @TusharGupta to be really picky - you are also wrong, you don't need an ID to update, you don't need a condition to be unique, UPDATE will quite happly update multiple rows if the condition meets true